# Rewrite URL in PHP

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite the following URL

www.mysite.com/mypage.php?userid=ca49b6ff-9e90-446e-8a92-38804f3405e7&roleid=037a0e55-d10e-4302-951e-a7864f5e563e

to

www.mysite.com/mypage/userid/ca49b6ff-9e90-446e-8a92-38804f3405e7/roleid/037a0e55-d10e-4302-951e-a7864f5e563e

The problem here is that the php file can be anything. Do i have to specify rules for each page on the .htaccess file?

how can i do this using the rewrite engine in php?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=htaccess+url+rewrite

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL rewriting advice please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051421/url-rewriting-advice-please)

Comment: I would advise you to not throw localized stuff into the .htaccess and instead use my solution where I offload the issue into a PHP script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the rewrite rule to work, you have to add this to your apache configs (in the virtualhost block):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/userid/([^/]*)/roleid/(.*)$ /$1.php?userid=$2&roleid=$3 [L,NS]
```

`RewriteRule` basically accepts two arguments. The first one is a regex describing what it should match. Here it is looking for the user requesting a url like `/<mypage>/<pid>/roleid/<rid>`. The second argument is where it should actually go on your server to do the request (in this case, it is your php file that is doing the request). It refers back to the groups in the regex using `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question has another point to it.
it is not necessary that mypage.php is the page that this rule applies to. it can be anyother page with the above querystrings. Will I have to provide the rules for each page or would I be able to specify a generic rule for all pages?

Comment: @AbishekRSrikaanth, you can provide the page name as part of the regex for the rule. I updated my answer to show how that would be done.

Comment: @Abishek: As Ben Lee says, you could simply use wildcards for the "something.php" part. However, your question implies that you want to go from the first URL to the second, and not vice versa. If that is the case (you want the first URL to be rewritten into the second), you should use my PHP solution and not a .htaccess. If you do mean a .htaccess you should edit your question!

Comment: @BenLee: why do you imply that the topic-poster confuses mod_rewrite with PHP? He never said he wants to use .htaccess/mod_rewrite. I think you misread the question... he doesn't want to go from the second URL to the first, but from the first to the second. For example to use the URL in an <a> link.

Comment: @WillemMulder, I am assuming the OP meant to say it the other way because nobody ever does a rewrite in the direction from "pretty url" => "ugly url" (or from "no query string" => "has a query string"). That wouldn't make any sense. Hence I assumed the OP meant to say a rewrite from the second url to the first url. (Since "rewrite" as a concept is not really directional, it can be easy to get these confused -- so I rely on past experience to make an assumption about the directionality).

Comment: @BenLee: That's right; nobody goes from pretty to ugly, hence he wants to go from the first (ugly) URL to the second (pretty) URL :)

Comment: @WillemMulder, you are confusing terms here. When you rewrite a url, what you are doing is taking a url that the user enters (the request url, which should be pretty) and converting it to a url that the backend uses (can be ugly, often contains a code extension like php). So a rewrite from B to A in a sense *means* "going from A to B". You are changing the way the user interacts with the application (chaging the URLs) from A to B by rewriting B to A.

Comment: That's true. For the user to see A instead of B, you need to rewrite B to A when he enters it. Still, if you want to *produce* these pretty A URLs, you need to either build them directly (preferred) or convert them from old ugly URLs. It is the latter that I assume the Topic Starter wants to know. Still, both our answers are useful, so I'll upvote yours regardless!

Answer (score 0):

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^mypage\/userid\/(([a-z0-9]).+)\/roleid\/(([a-z0-9]).+)$ www.mysite.com/mypage.php?userid=$1&roleid=$2
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. The OP says that "the php file could be anything" and wonders whether he/she needs a separate rule for each file. You have explained how to make a rewrite rule, which is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: what`s the problem? just delete 'mypage' in regex

Comment: @Bazzz, this answer is actually exactly what the OP asked for originally. He later updated his post to ask about how to make it work for multiple pages.

Comment: @Ben Lee fair enough, that I could not have known. I'm just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite the latter URL that is entered in the browser TO the first format, you  would want to use a .htaccess file.

However, if you want to *produce* the pretty URLs in PHP (e.g. for use in link tags), then you have two options.

- First, you could simply build the URL directly (instead of converting) which in my opinion is preferred.
- Second, you could rewrite the first (ugly) URL to the pretty latter URL. You would then need to use preg_replace() in PHP. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php for more info. Basically, you would want to use something like

  ```
  $rewrittenurl = preg_replace("@mysite\.com\/mypage.php?userid=(([a-z0-9\-]).+)\&roleid=(([a-z0-9\-]).+)$", "mysite.com/userid/$1/roleid/$2", $firsturl);
  ```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need a separate rule for every php file, you can make the filename variable in your regex something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(a-z0-9)/userid/([a-z0-9].+)/roleid/([a-z0-9].+)$ $1.php?userid=$2&roleid=$3
```